# Center two divs, one under the other

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center two divs one under the other, inside another div.
But that's the best result I got, in a responsive way.
[result I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMDoe.png)

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.cliente_info,
.cliente_table {
  display: inline-block;
}

.cliente_info {
  width: 90%;
  height: 45%;
  background-color: azure;
}

.cliente_table {
  width: 90%;
  height: 45%;
  background-color: rgb(156, 204, 204);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="cliente_info">
  </div>
  <div class="cliente_table">
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to get the divs to look like the following image.
[Result expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQonv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `flex-flow: column` to the `.content` class and changing the `inline-block` elements to `block`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding `flex-direction: column` to the `.content` class, you can add `justify-content: space-around` to get space before, between, and after each associated element. If you do not wish to do so, padding top and bottom can be applied instead to the `.content` class.

Answer (score 0):

**Here you can try this logic :**

```css
 .content {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      background-color: lightgray;
    }

    /* Height => (2 * 45%) = 90%  =>45% for cliente_info & 45% for cliente_table */
    .cliente_info,
    .cliente_table {
      width: 90%;
      height: 45%;
    }

    .cliente_info {
      background-color: cyan;
    }
    .cliente_table {
      background-color: orange;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="cliente_info"></div>
      <div class="cliente_table"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

## There are many notes here:

---

##### Note 1:

By default, the `flex` element has a `flex-direction` of row, so to make his children stands in a column set the `flex-direction` to column

---

##### Note 2:

If you want to control some elements with their parent using `flex` or `grid` for example, try avoiding to use the `display` for the children, because in most of the cases, it will be ignored and the alignment will come from the parent settings.

So, delete the `display: inline-block` from the children.

---

##### Note 3:

You're setting all dimensions of the `parent` and `children` in percentage, which means that the grand parent of the parent element must have a width and height, in your case, the `body` so that the parent elements knows what value he took his percentage.

Or just set a width and height without percentages.

---

#### The Code After Edits:

```css
body{
    width: 100vw; height: 100vh; margin: 0;
}

.content {
  height: 100%; width: 80%;
  display: flex; flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center; justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 5px; border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.cliente_info {
  width: 90%; height: 45%;
  background-color: azure;
}

.cliente_table {
  width: 90%; height: 45%;
  background-color: rgb(156, 204, 204);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="cliente_info"></div>
  <div class="cliente_table"></div>
</div>
```

Just note the lines: `1-3` and `7` in css, and the missing style of children display.

I think it's clear now, if anything is missing, just let me know.